# How to override css class set in iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have third party iframe widget component on my page. This is all I have as an HTML string in the body of my page. This iframe brings some custom button with style set by that widget.jsp. Chrome inspector doesn't show anything else except `<iframe>` component. But FireFox shows that button inside `<iframe>` with style class ".button"

```
<iframe src='https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/aaa/bbb/widget.jsp?par1='TEST%20BUTTON'></iframe>
```

[image]

So how do I override that .button style class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser security does not allow to manipulate third party iframe content via JavaScript. Adding a CSS from outside is also not possible.

The only way to change the style would be from within `widget.jsp`. Maybe whoever provides you that can also provide a URL parameter, which would allow you to change its appearance.