# How to modify value attribute and class of a HTML element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to transform this:

```
<input value="Étape 1/2" name="submitForm" type="submit" class="submit">
```

to this:

```
<input value="Étape suivante" name="submitForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary formdevis">
```

Comment: you can't change in third-party iframe elements :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859634/how-to-override-css-class-set-in-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/KlaussU/eh4wabj7/1/

```
<button onclick="change();">Change</button>
<input value="Étape 1/2" name="submitForm" type="submit" class="submit">
<script>
  function change() {
    $(".submit").attr("value", "Étape suivante");
    $(".submit").addClass("btn btn-large btn-primary formdevis");
      $(".submit").removeClass("submit");
  }
</script>
```